# VBA - Search text for partial string, copy entire string

Tags: string, vba, full-text-search

I have a series of files outlining different product builds, and each file is named with just the printer job number. What I would like to do is cycle through each such file in my folder, open it grab the product number, and rename the file with that string. The products would all begin with the same prefix, but the following digits are unique to each product. I've got it to the point where my macro prompts the user for that prefix, but I'm stumped as to how to search the .txt file for it, and then how to capture everything up to the next "space". Each product line begins with a different prefix, and may have a different number of following digits. It only needs to grab the first instance of the prefix, which so far has been line 3 -- but I don't want to limit it to only searching that line, as it may be different in the future.

Edit:
The pertinent info here is "2940UB200L". "2940" is the product line, given by the user, and the values following are unique to the assembly. However, there may be other products within the same product line listed below this header (I can't post that list). 100's of these Bills are in a folder, and each file is named with only the print job number. So far, I really only have code for a pop-up box requesting the product line prefix and a way to cycle through the folder. Everything else is bits and pieces that don't quite work together. In a given folder, everything SHOULD be from the same product line.

Sample text... Doesn't seem to be formatting the same in the preview as what I've pasted:

PRODUCTION PLANT                     INDENTED BILL
PARENT ITEM NO.             DESCRIPTION ROUND RING
2940UB200L                  ENGR DRAW 00000LM000/ZN31
                            STANDARD BATCH QUANTITY           1.000 RELATIVE SEQ   RELATIVE    SEQ   COMPONENT                       ENGINEERING       QUANTITY
LEVEL       NO.   ITEM NO.        DESCRIPTION     DRAWING NUMBER         PER

Working code:

```
Sub ChangeFileName()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ProdLine As String 'Product Line to search
Dim CatNum As String 'Full Part number
 'Get the folder object associated with the directory
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False

 'Close macro when no folder is selected
  If .Show <> -1 Then MsgBox "No folder selected! Exiting sub...": Exit Sub
  myDir = .SelectedItems(1)

  On Error Resume Next

  FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
  Err.Clear

  On Error GoTo 0

End With

 'Gives File list a header
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderName)
 'Prompts user for Product Line
ProdLine = InputBox("Enter product line prefix (example: 2940)")

 'Find Part Number
 'Change file name

End Sub
```

Thanks for any input

Comment: Post the code you have so far and an example of one of the files.